# When I execute the MATCH statement, it reports an error on NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

NebulaGraph version is master.
Deployment way is stand-alone.
Installation way is Docker.
Disk is SSD.
CPU is m1 16G.

The NebulaGraph master branch I deployed executes `match(m)-[:follow]->() return m limit 10` statement and reports an error
`-1005:Scan vertices or edges need to specify a limit number, or limit number can not push down`.

I checked several times but found nothing wrong. Anybody who can help revise the query I give?

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? Hint: your title should state part of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This limit cannot be pushed down, you have to put some other limit on m. For example:

```
match(m)-[:follow]->() where id(m)=="xxx" return m limit 10
```

```
match(m)-[:follow]->() where m.name=="xxx" return m limit 10
```